# Allowing Wordpress Users Multiple Logins

Tags: php, wordpress

I've got a client using a WordPress site. They've got users in their site that have a series of extra fields that they can fill out- these fields save as metadata for that user. The client now wants his 'manager' level users to be able to create extra username/password combinations that would allow access to that particular 'manager' account. All of those username/password combos would be able to edit their manager's profile fields but not manage the other username/password 'aliases' for that managers account.

I can't find anything similar available via plugin. Does anyone know of anything, or could recommend a specific course of action for me to take to create a plugin that would do this? I'm prepared to write a custom plugin for this, but I want to know I'm doing it correctly. Should I create a new user role that can not see their own profile but instead the profile of the user that created them? And then allow a specific role the ability to create a user of that new limited role?

Thoughts?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will have to create a extra table in database linked to wp_users with user id as foreign key and store user name and password there. but this process involves modification in wordpress admin files.

Comment: Could this not be done with just a plugin? Are there any hooks or things that would allow me to do my own authentication check before the wordpress check? Or... are there any particular reasons I should use wordpress users? I'm thinking that I shouldn't be creating my own authentication as wordpress has a particular way of dealing with passwords and I'd like to keep it consistent. I would wonder the feasibility of attempting my role limitations....